# Is it possible to use constants in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I want to have same margins, sizes etc. for same kinds of widgets. Is it possible to define constants and use them in Qt Designer?

(I want something similiar to eclipse GUI design of Android applications where I have global constants)

Comment: You may use stylesheets with global selectors.

Comment: I have checked stylesheets but it seems to me that you can't use it for layouts (padding for example). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Extra answer to comment, about layouts and styling:

You can not tune layout with QSS, because it is not a widget. But you may wrap content of layout into another widget.

So if you have next scheme:

`verticalLayout(margin: 5px) -> Your_widgets`

You should add extra/proxy widget:

`verticalLayout(margin: 0px) -> WRAPPER_WIDGET_with_verticalLayout(margin: 5px) -> Your_widgets`

So you are able to use selectors like: `#WRAPPER_WIDGET_with_verticalLayout QWidget{ border: 1px solid Red; }`